# useState() hook doesn't cause rerendering of the Component so that a Child is not updated as well

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a View where Users are loaded from an local Database on the Device. WHen the Task Componnet is clicked it should update and show a Checkmark in the Compoonent (this is what `checked` Prop is responsible for). But somehow after the first update of the `selected` State Array is updated from all Values false = not selected, to true, there is no rerendering of the Page happening...

Anyone sees a Mistake I made in the Code. because I tried much and it seems like I can't find it. Somehow I am still sure I made one, because according to the Docs the setSelected function should trigger rerendering when Value changes which the Array does!

Users.tsx (A Page of the App)

```
const Users: React.FC = () => {
...
return (<ScrollView style={styles.scrollview}>
            {contacts.length > 0 ? (
              contacts.map((c, index) => {
                return [
                  <Task
                    checked={selected[index]}
                    onSelect={(selected) => {
                      setSelected((preState) => {
                        preState[
                          index
                        ] = selected;
                        return [...preState];
                      });
                    }}
                    key={index}
                    name={
                      c.firstname +
                      " " +
                      c.lastname
                    }
                  />,
                  <Spacer
                    key={c.phone + c.email}
                    width="100%"
                    height={20}
                  />,
                ];
              })
            ) : (
              <Text style={styles.noContactsText}>
                No Customers created yet
              </Text>
            )}
          </ScrollView)
}
```

task.tsx (The Component which is rendered inside the Scrollview)

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  onSelect(selected: boolean);
  checked: boolean;
}
const Task: React.FC<Props> = ({
  name,
  onSelect,
  checked: checkedProp,
}) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setChecked(checkedProp);
  }, [checkedProp]);
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => {
        onSelect(!checked);
      }}
    >
      <Grid style={styles.root}>
        <Col size={10} style={styles.checkmark}>
          <View>
            {checked ? (
              <CheckmarkIcon />
            ) : undefined}
          </View>
        </Col>
        <Col size={90}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{name}</Text>
        </Col>
      </Grid>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};
```

I get no Exception or something else except for a non happening rerendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer was that the react-navigation doesn't cause an Update to a re visited Route at all. But it gives you the `useIsFocused()` Hook to combine with `useEffect()` like this:

```
const focused = useIsFocused();
//Gets called on each Visit of the Route/View
useEffect(()=>{...}, [focused]);
```